# How do i get the selected option Text using regular expression?

Tags: html, regex

I need the text between selected `<option></option>` tags from the html code below:

```
<select>

<option value="me=A29S2L940CQWBD" selected="selected">First</option>
<option value="search-alias=aps">Second</option>

</select>
```

I tried `/"selected">[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*/` but i am getting **'"selected">First'** which is ok but i am trying to get just **"First"**.
Please correct my regex and help me.

Comment: I'm not seeing your html markup.

Comment: @jameslafferty its <select>

<option value="me=A29S2L940CQWBD" selected="selected">First</option>
<option value="search-alias=aps">Second</option>

</select>

Comment: Which language are you using to perform the match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
var str = '<select><option value="me=A29S2L940CQWBD" selected="selected">First</option><option value="search-alias=aps">Second</option></select>';
console.log(str.match(/"selected">([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i got this thing:

```
(?<="selected">)(.*)<
```

can't get rid of last '<' sign (regex should be `(?<="selected">).*(?=<)` but for some reason it's not working in notepad++), but you can grab first matched group from there

Answer (score -1):

***I need the text between selected `<option></option>`***

If you just need `First` and `Second` as output you can do it without regex:

http://jsfiddle.net/TVnT6/

**Full code:**

```
<script> 
    function getOp(a)
    {
    alert(a);
    }
</script>
<select>

<option class="sel" value="me=A29S2L940CQWBD" selected="selected" onclick="getOp(this.innerHTML)">First</option>
<option class="sel" value="search-alias=aps" onclick="getOp(this.innerHTML)">Second</option>

</select>
```